# Using durandal dialog

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, durandal, single-page-application

Please help i'm using john papa's template for single page applications. The challenge i'm encountering right now is that, when the durandal modal dialog shows up on the middle, my ui on the background adjusts to the right side of the screen. I'm currently debugging why its happening, but have no luck on finding it yet. Thanks

Comment: check  whether you have added all the css file references...

Comment: Without some markup and code, you're not gonna get the answers you are looking for

Comment: Jayantha you are almost certainly correct, why don't you submit it as an answer?